# Replacing substrings in C without using string library functions

Tags: c, string, replace, append

While this code is hideous and I've clearly solved the problem incorrectly, the code works (for the moment). I want to mess around with it, but I truly don't know what I'm doing wrong here. The goal is to, **without using any built in functions**, take the string "This is a test" and replace the "te" with "gho" to spell out "This is a ghost".

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *s = "This is a test";
    char *newstring = malloc(strlen(s));


    for (int i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; i++){
        if (s[i] == 't' && s[i+1] == 'e') {
            newstring[i] = 'g';}
        else if (s[i] == 'e' && s[i+1] == 's') {
            newstring[i] = 'h';}
        else if (s[i] == 's' && s[i+1] == 't') {
            newstring[i] = 'o';
        }
        else if (s[i] == 't') {
            newstring[i] = 's';
        }
        else {
            newstring[i] = s[i];
        }
        }
    printf("%st",newstring);


    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to append characters to a new string in C so that I can maintain the integrity of the original string while just replacing single characters.

Comment: What is your question? Is it "how to append characters to a new string in C"?

Comment: @user3121023 this is true, I've adjusted it in my code. In my print statement, I have to manually add a "t" at the end; what can I do to avoid having to do that? I tried adding code under the last else if statement to say that, in addition to newstring[i] = 's'; newstring[i+1] = 't'. That didn't work.

Comment: I would split this into three functions: "find "te" in a string", "write "gho" at a position in a string" and "copy part of one string over the other.  By splitting it, I bet the complexity falls right off.

Comment: @MooingDuck sounds like a good way to tackle it. My problem is that I'm completely new to C and have no clue how to implement this! With regards to 'copying' part of one string to another, I did that above by setting the index values to each other. Not sure how to search for multiple characters in a string AND note which indices they exist at. I could basically say "take the part of string leading up to 'te' and copy to new string". Then, "ignore 'te' and insert 'gho'". Then, "copy everything after 'te' to the new string". It's just actually implementing it...

Comment: @user3121023 I can definitely get it to work that way if I mess around enough, but it's kind of just a workaround. Really, I'm supposed to be able to locate "te" and replace directly with "gho" while copying everything else, at the proper index, to the new string.

Comment: the system function: 'strstr()' does the job nicely.  If your not allowed to use strstr(), the google the source, place that source into a sub function of your code and use it.

Comment: you state that the code cannot use any of the system functions, but the posted code uses strlen(), malloc(), and printf()   BTW:  C does not have any builtin ability to perform any I/O.  That is why libraries like stdio.h and stdlib.h are almost always needed.  C does not have any builtin abillity to perform any string operations.  That is why libraries like string.h are almost always needed.

Comment: to avoid using strlen(), suggest: a sub function the takes a pointer to the string and returns the 'offset' to the '\0' byte, just like strlen().  see my answer for an example;

Comment: suggest looking for the sub string 'test' and when/if that sub string is found, then append 'ghost' onto the new string.  Then append any remaining characters from the original string.  that way the code is not trying to make changes if the full 'test' sub string is not available in the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should recognize a pattern in what you want to do. For a start, it's a useful trick to remember that you can fill out a new array like so:

```
int num = 0;
int buf[256];

buf[num++] = 123;
buf[num++] = 456;
buf[num++] = 789;
```

This is a shorthand. The line:

```
buf[num++] = 123;
```

Provides equivalent behavior to:

```
buf[num] = 123;
++num;
```

So what do we want to do here? We want to make a new string which is the same as the original except that it replaces "te" with "gho". So how about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    const char *s = "This is a test";
    int i = 0;
    int new_len = 0;

    // We don't know what the final size of the string will be, so
    // let's make one that's generally large enough. Can do more
    // elaborate things here if you want a really robust solution.
    char new_string[256] = {0};

    // For each character in the string:
    for (i=0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == 't' && s[i+1] == 'e')
        {
            // If we find "te", add "gho".
            new_string[new_len++] = 'g';
            new_string[new_len++] = 'h';
            new_string[new_len++] = 'o';

            // ... and skip one character to ignore both the 't' and the 'e'.
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise just add the same character.
            new_string[new_len++] = s[i];
        }
    }

    // Add the null terminator at the end of our new string.
    new_string[new_len] = '\0';

    // Output the new string.
    printf("%s\n", new_string);
}
```

Comment: Great effort ike, but you should revisit the part of the question that says **without using any built in functions** (emphasis in original). I bet you can do it.

Comment: sorry, per the OP, cannot use 'built in' functions  I.E. those functions supplied by a library.  so no 'string.h' allowed

Comment: Doh. I missed that part. I'm hoping `printf` is at least allowed.

Comment: hello all! I'm allowed to use printf!

Comment: Nice solution @Ike. Quick question: When you increment [new_len++], what does skipping the next character do? Let's say the indices that we find "te" at (in the original string) to be 4 and 5. That means that at indices 4, 5, and 6 in new_string, we have g, h, and o filled in respectively. What does skipping over index '6' in the original string do? Don't we just need to go to the very next two indices and add them (s and t)? Why do we need to skip the 6th index (not actually the 6th index, just in my bad example).

Comment: nvm, tried removing it and understand why it wouldn't work. thanks for the help.

Comment: An additional aspect to consider would be to create three variables, one to store the area before and after the 'te', one to store 'te' and one with 'gho' to replace the previous variable.

Comment: @Ike another question: when we first use [new_len++] within the if loop, isn't it equal to 0 since we initialized it outside of the function? It's never been incremented to keep up with i!

Comment: @karansatia The `++i` to skip the character is mainly emulating the effect of reading two characters (both the 't' and 'e' at one time and replacing it with "gho"). Otherwise it'll be like reading only 't' and replacing it with "gho".

Comment: @karansatia About `new_len++`, it is equal to 0 originally, and that sets it to 1, then 2, and 3, and so forth. Actually that one will not just keep up with the loop counter variable but get ahead of it at some point, since we write it out 3 times when adding "gho". You can think of it as the "write" position to the new string while `i` is the "read position" from the original string.

Comment: @Ike thanks for clarifying. Just to be sure: when we find the index value for i at which 't' is the read value, new_len is still set to 0 but new_len[0] is actually equal to s[i] since it is limiting the string being evaluated by saying "when we come across 't' and 'e'". Something along those lines?

Comment: It might help first to temporarily remove the `if (s[i] == 't' && s[i+1] == 'e')` and its body. Just look at: `for (i=0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) new_string[new_len++] = s[i];`. When you do that, you see how it's just copying a string from `s` to `new_string`.

Comment: First `i` is equal to 0, and we basically execute `new_string[0] = s[0]`, incrementing `new_len` post. Next `i` is equal to 1, so we execute `new_string[1] = s[1]`, and so forth.

Comment: When you first find 't' and 'e', `new_len` will be set to the same value as `i`. Check out the `else` part which keeps up with the loop counter. But since we do `new_len++` three times when we encounter "te", at that point the write index (`new_len`) actually goes slightly ahead of the loop counter (by 1 extra character, since we write "gho" in response to reading "te").

Comment: @karansatia BTW, I'm assuming you don't know how to use a debugger yet. If you want to "cheat" and jump to the top of your class, learning how to use your debugger will accelerate your understanding of code 10x, letting you see exactly what's happening to each variable with each line of code and how the computer branches between them. If you have an IDE like Visual Studio or Eclipse, it's often as easy as setting a breakpoint on a line of code you're interested in and just running the debugger, then stepping over/into lines of code. GDB is a bit harder, but worth it.

Comment: @Ike I'm really stupid...I didn't even read on to see that the new_len increments in the else statement HAH. Now I'm trying to understand pointers so I can write a function to take any string (and using those pointers, dynamically use malloc to work for any string length). The function parameters would be (original string, string to look for, replacement string). Losing my mind over this.

Comment: @Ike I'm getting used to using the debugger in xcode...for a while I forgot it was even there, and it's really been helpful in adjusting my code to work.

Comment: Ah, xcode is also nice. I think you can hover your mouse over variables there to see what value they have. When you're losing your mind, I recommend writing out the logic in your code by hand, even unrolling loops as I did above showing what happens when i=0, i=1, i=2, etc. But you can skip the tedium of doing all this by hand if you let the debugger do it for you and show you exactly what is happening at every single stage of your code.

Comment: Remember that computers are really simple "creatures". They can't remember what happened 1 second ago unless a programmer put aside something in memory for it to 'remember'. They need things broken down into the tiniest babysteps. We think more in big steps which is why it's useful to see patterns in code as forming a bigger thought, like `new_string[new_len++] = some_character;` being equivalent to "write one character to the new string." It fits our human way of thinking better.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *s = "This is a test";
int len = 0;

while(s[len++]);//strlen(s) + 1
for (int i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; i++){
    if (s[i] == 't' && s[i+1] == 'e') {//count "te"
        ++len;
        ++i;
    }
}

char *newstring = malloc(len);
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; i++){
    if (s[i] == 't' && s[i+1] == 'e') {
        newstring[j++] = 'g';
        newstring[j++] = 'h';
        newstring[j++] = 'o';
        ++i;
    } else {
        newstring[j++] = s[i];
    }
}
newstring[j] = '\0';
puts(newstring);
free(newstring);
```

Comment: per the OP, cannot use 'built in' functions (those from a library) so no malloc() and no free() allowed.   How the OP is expected to display anything to the user is a bit of a question because 'puts()' is one of those 'built in' functions from a library.

Comment: @user3629249 OP used `malloc`. also can use VLA.

Comment: I think the OP might have not fully understood the limitations given to them.  In any case, an array can be defined on-the-fly after calculating how many bytes is needed.

Comment: I think I'm ok to use malloc, I don't really understand the concept of "free". I think I need to read up on pointers a bit more.

Comment: @karansatia it is not `pointers` per se, but blocks of memory you create with `malloc` or `calloc`, that you are then responsible to `free` when you are done using the memory.  The only place pointers come into play is that both `malloc` and `calloc` return the start address to the newly created block of memory. Memory addresses are stored in pointers. (e.g. `int *array = malloc (20 * sizeof (int));` creates a block of memory to hold 20 integers with the starting address to that block stored in `array`). When done with `array`, you must `free (array);` To return the memory to the system.

Answer (score 0):

```
int myStrLen( char * );


int myStrlen( char *testStr )
{
    int rtnCount;

    for( rtnCount = 0; testStr[rtnCount]; rtnCount++ ) {;}

    return( rtnCount );
} // end function: myStrlen
```

other string functions can be implemented in a similar manner.

then the 'home grown' string functions could be used similar to this:

```
// get length of original string
int oldStringLen = myStrLen( s );

// provide room on the stack for the new string
char newString[oldStringLen+2] = {'\0'};

// search for occurrence of string to be replaced
char * targetString = myStrStr( s, "test" );
if( NULL == targetString )
{ // then target string not found
    // handle error??
    return( -1 );
}

// implied else, target string found in 's'

// copy first part of original string
myStrNCpy( newString, s, (targetString - s) +1 );

// append the replacement string
myStrCat( newString, "ghost" );

// append remainder of original string
myStrCat( newString, &targetString[4] );
```

does the code need to keep looking in the original string
for other possible replacements?

of course, how to display the result to the user
may be 'interesting' since C has no ability to perform any I/O
without using something like the stdio.h library

Comment: `char newString[oldStringLen+2] = {'\0'};` invalid syntax. _variable-sized object may not be initialized_